# How to do this better without repeating jQuery addClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

On my forms when the page loads I make the default text in the inputs light gray like this:

```
var formInputs = $('#notifyForm input');
formInputs.addClass('defaultText');
```

Then I have them turn back to black on focus using removeClass.  This all works fine.  The problem I've run into is, if there's an error and the page reloads to display a PHP error msg, the user's text that's still in the inputs, turns gray.  My solution for this is:

```
formInputs.addClass(function()
{
    if($(this).attr('value') === $(this).attr('title'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('defaultText');
    }
});
```

But I know there has to be something wrong with calling addClass inside an addClass handler.  Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the function you pass to `addClass` you can return a string which will be the class name you want to add. Try this:

```
formInputs.addClass(function() {
    if (this.value === this.title)
        return 'defaultText';
});
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks Rory.  I knew there had to be a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer provided by Rory, it's possible to select by the criteria prior to the `addClass()`:

```
 formInputs.filter(function() {
    return this.value === this.title;
 }).addClass('defaultText');
```

Incidentally, and somewhat to my surprise, the `addClass()` approach is around half as fast (43% slower, in Chrome 23/Win XP) as the `filter()` method (still a fairly minor optimisation, though).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).